# Maven don't execute junit test

Tags: maven, junit

I'm trying to test this project: https://github.com/deglans/jenktest
but maven say that:

```
$ mvn clean install    
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] jenktest
[INFO] hello
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jenktest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ jenktest ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ jenktest ---
[INFO] Installing /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/pom.xml to /home/deglans/.m2/repository/io/github/deglans/jenktest/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/jenktest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building hello 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ hello ---
[INFO] Deleting /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/hello/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ hello ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ hello ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/hello/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ hello ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/hello/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ hello ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/hello/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ hello ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ hello ---
[INFO] Building jar: /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/hello/target/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ hello ---
[INFO] Installing /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/hello/target/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/deglans/.m2/repository/io/github/deglans/hello/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /documenti/deglans/Programs/IdeaProjects/jenktest/hello/pom.xml to /home/deglans/.m2/repository/io/github/deglans/hello/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] jenktest ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.449 s]
[INFO] hello .............................................. SUCCESS [  1.715 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.360 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-16T11:41:59+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/48M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the warning and why maven completely skip the test phase?

The final purpose of this work is to test email jenkins feature, but for now I'm blocked by this problem...

Thanks

Comment: Run Maven with option `-X` to see debug messages.

Comment: The warning is because a library is not yet upgraded to Java 9

Answer (score 2):

### Summary

You need to either rename `GreetingTests.java` to `GreetingTest.java`, or update your `maven-surefire-plugin`. Updating surefire plugin can provide better pattern for [inclusions of tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html). You can declare it in project's parent POM `./pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- ... -->

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

### Detail

> What is the warning and why maven completely skip the test phase?

Maven didn't skip the test phase. Maven unit tests are executed by `maven-surefire-plugin`, and it has been triggered correctly:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ hello ---
```

You need to rename your test to `GreetingTests.java` to `GreetingTest.java`. Because the `surefire-plugin:2.12.4` does not recognize pattern `*Tests.java`, as documented [here](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.12.4/maven-surefire-plugin/src/site/apt/examples/inclusion-exclusion.apt.vm):

> By default, the plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - `"**/Test*.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java
>     filenames that start with "Test".
> - `"**/*Test.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java
>     filenames that end with "Test".
> - `"**/*TestCase.java"` - includes all of its subdirectories and all java
>     filenames that end with "TestCase".